# Autofill Custom List

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to code a schedule generator in Excel using formulas or VBA that can automatically fill in the correct cells with data from a custom list (it can be stored anywhere - another spreadsheet, somewhere in the same sheet).  Does anyone know an easy way to do this using VBA/Excel formulas or some other method (maybe even a better program to do it in)?

A user should type the start date in a cell and then it automatically fills in the same data into the weekdays, skipping weekends and holidays, which are also user inputted somewhere in a spreadsheet.

[This picture explains what I am trying to accomplish:](http://directlinkupload.com/uploads/174.50.124.15/Capture.PNG)

[image: SO25446576 question example]

There would be a place to input a new class and start date and the rest would auto fill.  The custom list would be the titles (i.e. Database Basics, Tables, Primary Keys, Foreign Keys and so on)

The top two rows are date and day of week (that part is easy) but then give a start date fill in the list (until you reach the end of the list) in the weekdays but do not fill in weekends or user chosen holidays.  Ideally this would work for every row.  So if I have multiple start dates then maybe rows 3,4,5 would have different schedules but I can see where they coincide and do not based on this simple view.

Answer (score 0):

This is a description of a technique that you may adapt for your use.  Say we want to auto-fill dates *(working days)* in row #1 based on a staring date in cell **A1.**

Leave **A1** empty. Format the cells in row #1 as *Date.*

In **B1** enter:

```
=IF(A1="","",WORKDAY(A1,1))
```

and copy across.  Now when a date is entered in **A1,** the rest of row #1 will follow suit.

Comment: that is very helpful for that portion but what about filling in the classes based on a start date and skipping a holiday.  Could you provide an example with 2 classes that start 1 day apart in the same week with a holiday on the wednesday? and then maybe go 1 or 2 days into the following week.  Because the classes need to be stored on a separate sheet or somewhere in the same sheet to draw from.  And it needs to iterate through them until the end.

Comment: @billmann A different technique would be needed based upon a *Lookup* of the first element of the autofill.